# File not found when loading from assets?

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, assets

I included several pre-made .png files in my assets folder, but only some of them are getting through without error:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
Inputstream in = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

where `assetName` is a `String` containing something like "myPic.png".

It seems to work for some of the files, but for others it throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: myPic.png` even though I see it right there in the Assets folder alongside plenty of other files that seem to be making the cut.

Comment: Look inside the APK itself and see if the assets are there. An APK is just a ZIP-style archive, so there are plenty of tools that will let you examine what is inside.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, those assets are not in the APK, but this was predictable because they're not being found for some reason in the first place

Comment: Do you have sub-folders in assets?

Comment: No, all in the same folder. All assets are lumped together in `AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppName/app/src/main/assets/`

Comment: "this was predictable" -- not necessarily. The APK might have the assets, but `AssetManager` was not allowing access to them for some reason. But, since the assets are missing, the problem is in your build process. That will be difficult to debug without a [mcve]. You might consider posting a screenshot of your `assets/` contents somewhere, link to it from your question, and give us a roster of what is and is not actually in the APK.

Comment: And now it's working after I closed/reopened my main project. :( color me confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently closing / reopening the project in Android Studio was enough to get it to work correctly. No idea why it wasn't noticing all the assets in the first place, but now it does after restarting.

Comment: I just spent 45 minutes chasing this same problem, with different naming combinations and digging into permissions for the assets/ folder... All it took was an Android Studio restart. Looks like asset changes require a full rebuild from `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

Comment: As above, wasted lot of time, in my case because I was placing the folder under `src/main/res` (together with layouts, drawables, ...), and not under `src/main` as it has to be.

Comment: re-create the file on assets make it work for me (haven't tried to restart Android studio yet), and we can use *mContext.assets.list("path")* to list out all loaded files

Comment: If restarting the editor doesn't work, try restarting windows. If this doesn't help try switching houses. In the end restart the universe. We may never know where were the hidden bugs lurking.

Comment: DIdn't work for me. Working in one project, but not another. Can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running into this during an Android Instrumentation Test, the issue can be fixed by changing this:

```
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(YOUR_FILE)
```

to this:

```
InputStream inputStream = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().
     getContext().getAssets().open(YOUR_FILE);
```

The application provider knows to redirect resource requests to your instrumentation resources and then fallback to the application under test, but it does not have the same intelligence for assets

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the names of your variables correspond to the name of your files, they are case sensitive. That could be why some file are not being read.

Comment: The cases/names are exactly the same