# java.io.FileNotFoundException, Can't read from text file in assets folder with variable string in file name | kotlin - android studio

Tags: android, string, file, kotlin, path

I am trying to read from a text file located in the assets folder. I tried this code and it works perfectly:

```
val path = "Descriptions/Apple/Apple_Description.txt"

val text = application.assets.open(path).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

But I need the file name to be a variable and this path to change depending on it, so I tried this code:

```
val item = "Apple"

val path = "Descriptions/${item}/${item}_Description.txt"

val text = application.assets.open(path).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

but the app crashes and gives me this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Descriptions/Apple/Apple_Description.txt
```

Can anyone please help me? I know it might be a silly question but I'm a beginner.

Thank you

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280121/file-not-found-when-loading-from-assets) is pretty old, but it might still be relevant. Have you tried restarting Android Studio/rebuilding the project? You can also try printing the result of [assets.list](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetManager#list(kotlin.String)) to confirm what the app sees.

Comment: I tried multiple times, still same error